# Yes/No percentage in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a table of records, where each record has 1) **unique submission number** and a column 2) **Tool Indicator** that has Yes or No value based on whether it has any tool associated or no tools and third column is 3) **Tool type** : that further indicates whether that tool type is a Rater or Walkaway or No tool associated. The last column 4) is the **Effective year**

I have four columns as below:

```
Column 1: list of submission numbers ( this is like a valid file id, for each record in the table)

Column 2 is visualized as slicer :

 Tool indicator = "Yes" or "No" (Yes&No are the values of the column)

Column 3 is visualized as slicer : 

 Tool Type : "Rater" or "Walkaway" or "Null" (null means there is no tool associated with the account)

Column 4 : Effective year
```

I'm looking to find the total percentage of the Rater and walkaway tool with respective to total submissions and for a selected effective date. Any thoughts on how can I achieve this is bar chart with percentage card on each bar.

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what you are trying to do. Can you make some sort of mock-up?

Comment: Right now, I am using this to find the percentage of rater.. % Rater = CALCULATE(COUNT(View_AUS_MissingRaterTool[Tool_Desc]), View_AUS_MissingRaterTool[Tool_Desc] = "Rater")

Answer (score 0):

I dont think any calculations are necessary.

I would just use the visual: 100% stacked column chart, and set Axis = Year, Legend = Tool_desc, Value = Submission Number (set to Count aggregation).